# Cordova, save update until internet comes on

Tags: rest, http, cordova

I'm trying to make an app using Corodva and I want to be able to save the data if there is no internet connection and automatically update when there is an internet connection.

Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done it by using local storage in html 5.First store the user data in local storage,next setup a function that check for internet connection every time app launches,if true make server request to store the data.After success of server request delete data from the local storage